# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; while adding database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Error
SQL query:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `ospos_sales_ibfk_3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES  `ospos_vehicles` (`person_id`);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>    near '`` ADD CONSTRAINT `ospos_sales_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `ospos ``' at line 1

Comment: `alter table tablename add constraint ...`

Comment: Show the lines you have before this line.

Comment: Where is this query coming from -- did you write it yourself, did it come from an application, or is it generated by phpMyAdmin when you're trying to do some action?

Answer (score 0):

add ALTER TABLE in your mysql query and also remove quotes. try this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT ospos_sales_ibfk_3
FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES ospos_vehicles(person_id);
```

i think it should work without errors, you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp it is correct way.